# How to Remote desktop into UBUNTU 19.04 from Windows 10, over home wifi with sudo access

Tags: 19.04, remote-access

Any recommendations on how I can connect from Windows 10, to Ubuntu 19.04 over home wifi (but preferably from anywhere on the internet), and do a screenshare of Ubuntu desktop, and control the desktop from Windows?

I tried using Chrome Remote Desktop, which sounded like an amazingly easy solution, except that CRD did not load the sudo user/created a new desktop environment, and following directions from here simply made my Ubuntu computer unusable.

I also tried the windows Remote desktop connection, which did roughly the same thing as above (with a weird interface).

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The couple of times I tried to use RDP to access my Ubuntu machines from Windows it didn't work (my personal experience) so I decided to use VNC.

I used [these instructions](https://www.linuxtopia.org/HowToGuides/VNC_setup_Linux_Windows.html) to setup VNC Server on my Ubuntu machines and then access the machine using a VNC Client from windows with SSH.

To start, run the command `sudo apt install tightvncserver` on the Ubuntu machine

> Once you have VNC installed you will need to specify a password to
>   protect access to the VNC server. To do this run:
>
> ```
> vncpasswd
> ```
>
> and enter a suitable password.
>
> #### Starting and Stopping the VNC Server
>
> The next thing you need to learn how to do is start and stop the VNC
>   server. Start the VNC Server with the following command:
>
> ```
> vncserver
> ```
>
> Assuming no problems are encountered vncserver will output a message
>   that looks something like:
>
> ```
> New 'myhost:1 (src)' desktop is myhost:1
>
> Creating default startup script /home/neil/.vnc/xstartup
> Starting applications specified in /home/neil/.vnc/xstartup
> Log file is /home/neil/.vnc/myhost:1.log
> ```
>
> The key information here is that vncserver has started up an X server
>   as display :1 on system "myhost" and that it has created a
>   sub-directory called .vnc in the home directory of the user that
>   started the server containing a startup script called xstartup. In
>   addition it has also created a log file that can be reviewed to
>   diagnose any problems should the server have failed to start.
>
> To stop the VNC server simpy run the following command:
>
> ```
> vncserver -kill :1
> ```
>
> where the :1 matches the display that was indicated when vncsever
>   started up. This will display something along the lines of:
>
> ```
> Killing Xvnc process ID 15609
> ```
>
> A useful point to note here is that process being killed in called
>   Xvnc. Xvnc is the the actual VNC server process. The vncserver command
>   we ran to launch the VNC server is actually a shell script that sets
>   up the environment prior to launching the Xvnc process.
>
> #### Configuring the Desktop Environment to be Launched by VNC
>
> The next step is to configure what gets started up when the VNC server
>   is launched. As outlined previously the first time a user starts
>   vncserver the .vnc directory is created in their home directory.
>   Change directory to $HOME/.vnc and load the xstartup file into an
>   editor. It should appear as follows:
>
> ```
> #!/bin/sh
>
> # Uncomment the following two lines for normal desktop:
> # unset SESSION_MANAGER
> # exec /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc
>
> [ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup [ -r
> $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources xsetroot -solid grey
> vncconfig -iconic & xterm -geometry 80x24+10+10 -ls -title
> "$VNCDESKTOP Desktop" & twm &
> ```
>
> These commands perform some basic tasks such as setting the background
>   of the X window, launching an X terminal window and finally launching
>   the twm window manager. The twm window manager is a very good
>   lightweight window manager. Another good lightweight manager is the
>   Motif Window Manager (mwm). Those familiar with the Common Desktop
>   Environment (CDE) on Solaris, HP and IBM systems may want to change to
>   the "twm &" to "mwm &" in the xstartup script.
>
> Another option is to launch the GNOME or KDE desktop environments. To
>   launch the GNOME desktop environment change the twm line in xstartup
>   to:
>
> ```
> gnome-session &
> ```
>
> Similarly to launch the KDE desptop environment change the line to:
>
> ```
> startkde &
> ```
>
> Feel free to add other commands to the xstartup script. For example if
>   you would like your favorite mail tool or development IDE to launch
>   automatically then xstartup is the place to do it.
>
> #### Installing the VNC Viewer Client
>
> Having selected the desktop environment you would like to use the next
>   step is to install the client side VNC viewer. On Linux and Unix
>   systems the viewer is called vncviewer. Check to see if you already
>   have VNC installed on the client system. If it is not already
>   installed or you are running on Windows we once again recommend that
>   you download TightVNC from the [site](https://www.tightvnc.com/download.html).
>
> #### Establishing a Secure Shell connection between the two systems
>
> For security reasons it is recommended that the VNC communication take
>   place through an encrypted secure tunnel connection. On Linux or Unix
>   this can be achieved using the ssh command. On Windows we recommend
>   that you use PuTTY which is freely available from [putty.nl](https://www.putty.nl/download.html)
>
> By default the VNC server will communicate on port 59xx where xx
>   represents the display number. If vncserver announces that it is
>   running as display :1 then the port being used is 5901. If it tells
>   you it is display :2 then port 5902 is being used and so on.
>
> Supposing you have the VNC running on display :1 on a system called
>   myhost then you would need to establish an ssh connection as follows:
>
> Linux:
>
> ```
> ssh -L 5901:localhost:5901 myhost
> ```
>
> Windows using PuTTY:
>
> 1. Start PuTTY, enter the hostname or IP address of the system running VNC server. In our example this is "myhost"
> 2. Set the "SSH" toggle.
> 3. Select the "Tunnels" option from beneath SSH in the "Category" list and enter the following information:
>
>    ```
>    Source port: 5901 Destination: myhost:5901
>    ```
> 4. Save the profile you have entered by selecting "Session" from the Category list, entering name in the "Saved Sessions" text field and
>      press "Save"
> 5. Press the "Open" button to establish the secure connection.
>
> In both the case of Linux and Windows you will be prompted for a
>   password for the user under which you are logging in.
>
> #### Launching the VNC Viewer Client
>
> Assuming all went smoothly with the VNC server installation and that
>   you have established a secure shell connection using the appropriate
>   port (in our example 5901) you can now launch the VNC viewer client.
>   On Linux or UNIX this is done as follows:
>
> ```
> vncviewer localhost:1
> ```
>
> On Window using TightVNC simply launch the TightVNC viewer and enter
>   localhost:1 into the Connection details dialog and press "OK".
>
> In both cases you will prompted for a password. This is the password
>   that you specified when you ran vncpasswd earlier. After short delay
>   you should see a large window appear dispalaying your Linux desktop
>   and you can work with it as if you were sitting in front of your
>   console.